# Adobe PDF Printer Settings: Windows sytem font list incomplet / not updated after font installation

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat, print-to-pdf, embedded-fonts

Question: How can I get the Adope PDF printer to refresh / update this list? Do I have to reinstall Adobe Acrobat?

I manually installed a few fonts to C:\Windows\Fonts, but they do not show up in the 'Font Source' list in the settings dialog of the Adobe PDF printer.

The problem is that now the font is not embedded when printing e.g. from Excel, except when unchecking the checkbox 'Rely on system fonts only'. But on another (older) machine, the font shows up in the list and is embedded without changing that default setting.

[image]

[image]

Edit: I 'installed' by opening 'shell:fonts' in Windows Explorer and selecting 'Organize - Paste' (while having the font file on the system clipboard):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'manually installed' I'm guessing you merely copied/moved the fonts to that folder.
You should right click > Install from Explorer, which should correctly register them with the system.

Alternatively, from Windows Settings > Personalisation > Fonts, drag to the Add Fonts area in the top of the window.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question explaining what I did exactly. I will try with right-click install.

Comment: I worked, thanks! I deleted the fonts and installed with right-click. Now they appear in the list and are embedded without changing the settings.